# how to convert this excel formula in english words?

Tags: excel

can someone please translate this excel spreadsheet cell formula in english words ?

```
=ROUND(IF(F28 < 1568,2.5,IF(F28 < 2491,0.004873 * F28-5.142,0.02269*F28^0.7329)),2)
```

am creating a program based from that formula, but i don't understand which one will go first. atleast i understand this part IF(F28 is less than 1568) ...then what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from the outer if statement and move inwards.  The comma in the `IF` function separates the statements like :

boolean expression, true part, and false part

The following is the psuedo code of the above.  All the Round are to two decimal places.

```
IF (F28 < 1568) THEN
  ROUND (2.5)
ELSE IF (F28 < 2491) THEN
  ROUND (0.004873 * F28 - 5.142)
ELSE
  ROUND (0.02269 * F28^0.7329)
```

Comment: also `ROUND(number, 2)` will round to 2 decimal places

Answer (score 2):

If the value in cell F28 is less than 1568, then the value in this cell will be 2.5 rounded to 2 decimal places - i.e. 2.5

If the value in cell F28 is 1568 or more, but less than 2491, then the value in this cell will be:
          0.004873 multiplied by [the value in cell F28 minus 5.142], rounded to 2 decimal places

Otherwise (i.e. the value in cell F28 is 2491 or more) the value in this cell will be: 0.02269 multiplied by [the value in cell F28 to the power of 0.7329], rounded to 2 decimal places

Answer (score 1):

You will round the following in this order:

- Smaller than 1568 = `2.5`
- Bigger than/Equal 1568 but smaller than 2491 = `0.004873 * F28-5.142`
- Bigger than/Equal 2491 = `0.02269*F28^0.7329`

Comment: What is the Forumla doing for exactly 1568 and 2491 ? :) ->Add Equal ;)

Answer (score 1):

Basically that means this:

```
IF F28 is smaller than 1568 then use 2.5
IF F28 is larger or equal to 1568 but smaller than 2491 then use 0.0004873 * F28 - 5.142
IF F28 is larger or equal to 2491 then use 0.02269 * F28^0.7329

Round the outcome to 2 digits.
```

Comment: The Forumula uses "<" for the if-part which means >= for the ELSE case. So equal needs to be added.